# Need some help in doing this through recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

Whis and Beerus are playing a new game today . They form a tower of N coins and make a move in alternate turns . Beerus gets to play the first move . In one move player can remove 1 or X or Y coins from the tower . The person to make the last move wins the Game . Can you find out who wins the game ? Return 1 if Beerus will win and 0 if Whis will win.

Need to do this problem through recursion.

here is what i have tried.

```
public  static int solve(int n,int x,int y,int k){
if(n==0 && k%2!=0)
    return 1;
if(n==0)
    return 0;
if(n<0)
    return 0;

int z=solve(n-1,x,y,k+1)+solve(n-x,x,y,k+1)+solve(n-y,x,y,k+1);
if(z>0 && k%2==0)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;

    }
```

here i have taken k as an indicator as to who 's turn it is, according to if it is even or odd.

for input (3,2,3,0) expected o/p : 1 actual o/p : 1

for input(4,2,3,0) expected o/p: 0 actual o/p : 0

for input(7,2,3,0) expected o/p : 1 actual o/p : 0

for input(8,2,3,0) expected o/p : 0 actual o/p : 0
What is that i am doing wrong here?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me

Comment: And hint: use variable names that are meaningful to humans. There is no point in using single characters for everything. It is not 1970, and you aren't programming in Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static final int Beerus = 1;
static final int Whis = 0;

static int solve(int n, int x, int y, int player) {
    int opponent = 1 - player;
    int winner = opponent;
    if (n >= 1)
        winner = solve(n - 1, x, y, opponent);
    if (winner != player && n >= x)
        winner = solve(n - x, x, y, opponent);
    if (winner != player && n >= y)
        winner = solve(n - y, x, y, opponent);
    return winner;
}
```

test cases:

```
@Test
public void testSolve() {
    assertEquals(Beerus, solve(3, 2, 3, Beerus));
    assertEquals(Whis, solve(4, 2, 3, Beerus));
    assertEquals(Beerus, solve(7, 2, 3, Beerus));
    assertEquals(Whis, solve(8, 2, 3, Beerus));
}
```